# I would like to add content to the popover on init instead of inline

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, popover

How can I add `content` on inititialization?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
       trigger: 'click',
       html: true,
       placement:'top',
       content: 'sjk hgksjhdlgkjlskjklg' // Here
   })    
});
```

Comment: Can you expand your question and add some more information regarding versions and what you've tried and the results. The more information you provide, the easier it becomes for other people to help you.

Comment: i'm using bootstarp v.4, but my requirement is to display the popover with two different types of contents for every "td" in that popover before and after the "td" edit.  If the TD is in edit mode I need to include approve / reject actions in that popover.   After that successful edit operation when the TD is saved, then the content is need to be replaced with date of approval and status of that particular TD.      Please suggest me.

Comment: Please add more relevant code in the question